# How to access an info-component in a react-leaflet and next.js app?

Tags: leaflet, react

I am currently working on an app that displays a map using react leaflet and Next.js. Now I want to display an info-box with some useful data. The problem I have right now is that when I hover over the info-box, I cannot highlight the text inside the box and I also cannot click on a button or link. Now to make things a little easier I started with a "click"-event-listener. However this event-listener only works if I focus the info-box manually with the developer-tools. If I click on the info-box, it does not recognize my cursor...
Here is my (relevant) code:

```
function InfoBox({ data /*scope*/ }) {

  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  let infoBox;
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', () => setState(false));
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', () => setState(false));
  }, []);

  const onButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setState(!state);
  };
  console.log('state', state);
  if (data != null) {
    infoBox = (
      <div className="infobox_oben" id="startscreen">
             ...

      </div>);}
else{
infoBox = (
  <h4>
    <i>no info...</i>
  </h4>
);
}
  return (
    <>
  <button
    ref={divRef}
    className="info leaflet-top leaflet-right"
    id="startscreen1"
    onClick={onButtonClick}
  >
    
    {infoBox}
  </button>
</>
 );
}

export default InfoBox;
```

Here are some screenshots of the app:
[image: on the right you can see the infobox. When I hover it I acually move the map beneath]

[image: focus via dev-tools and hitting enter]

[image: console.log(state)]

[image: console.log(state)]